# Creation order in UIBinder widgets using UiField and UiFactory

Tags: gwt, uibinder

In my scenario (amendments welcome) I have a main page with a navigation and a content panel:

```
main
 |
 +--- Navigation (sets contents in ContentPage)
 |
 \--- ContentPage
```

Now, `Navigation` needs a reference to `ContentPage` so it can actually change the contents. That means when `main` is built, it needs to pass `ContentPage` to `Navigation`. This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
public class Main extends Composite {

    @UiField
    Panel contentPanel;

    @UiFactory
    Navigation makeNavigation() {
        return new Navigation(contentPanel);
    }

    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Middle> {
    }

    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    public Main() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

The problem is that, at the time makeNavigation is called, the  `UiField contentPanel` has not yet been set (it's null). I guess this is reasonable, since I have no guarantees `initWidget` has been called.

So, am I approaching this wrong? Is there a way to choose a creation order?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the widget instantiation order is the order of apparition in the ui.xml file, so if you want your contentPanel to be instatiated before the navigation, you have to put it before in the xml.

And I agree, this is not a solution...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! that would help, but it's not very robust to future changes, as you point out.

Answer (score 0):

So far I've gotten things to work using the following work around:

```
public class Middle extends Composite {

    @UiField
    Panel contentPanel;

    @UiField
    Navigation navigation;

    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Middle> {
    }

    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    public Middle() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        navigation.setContentPanel(contentPanel);
    }
}
```

This guarantees that `contentPanel` exists, but sort of splits the build phase of the `Navitagion` page into two steps. Is this a "community-approved" approach?